# Set the Matlab GUI?

Tags: matlab, user-interface, image-processing

I want to make a Matlab GUI.

Here is the design of my GUI

[image]

In my GUI there are 2 Group Button, 1 Command Button, 3 Edit box and 2 Radio Button.

So, I want :

1>> If I accessed the "radio1" then the "radio 2" become invisible (cannot accesed) and also with the "Group Button 2 (all properties in Group Button2)" (become invisible / cannot accesed).

2>> If I accessed the radio2 in Group Button1, then the "radio1" and the "edit Box 1" cannot accesed.

3>> If I accesed the Group Button 2 (the edit box 2 and 3), then all the properties in Group button 1 become invisible / cannot accesed.

How to do that.. Because in my Matlab File, there are only Comand button function created..

Thankss

I really appreciated all the answer :)

Comment: You can set properties using the `set(handle_name,property,property_value)` and get properties using `get(handle_name,property)`.  See [uicontrol properties](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/uicontrol_props.html) for additional information.  As a hint, check out the `Enable` property.

Comment: You may need to add the [drawnow](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/drawnow.html) command so that the gui refresh.

Answer (score 1):

> How to do that.. Because in my Matlab File, there are only Comand button function created..

You can create your own sub-functions and use them as callbacks:

```
function MyGUI()

%   Create the GUI
gui = createMyGUILayout();

% Assign Callback Function
set(gui.SaveBtn, 'Callback', @SaveSettings_callback);

% Declare Callbacks
    function SaveSettings_callback(~, ~)
        config = SaveConfig(gui); %#ok
        [file, dir] = uiputfile('config.mat','Save Configuration');
        if ischar(dir)
            save([dir file], 'config');
        end
    end

end
```

Comment: Do u know why i cannot disable my edit box. Here is my code for disable the edit box.  I have tried "set(handles.edit2,  'Enable','inactive');" and "set(handles.edit2,  'Enable','off');" but there is not effect. edit2 is tag for my Text Box..

Comment: set(..., 'Enable', 'off'); should really work. Are you sure you've got the right handle? As in: `handles.edit2 = uicontrol(...)`

Comment: It's solve. The problem was because i put the Edit Box in Button Groups and it didnt work. After i put the Edit Box in Panel. It workss..

Comment: I have another problem.. Do u know how to call the value of radio button into another Function. Here is my Code  "function radiobutton2_Callback(hObject, eventdata, handles)
if (get(hObject,'Value') == get(hObject,'Max'))
     set(handles.uipanel5,'Visible', 'off')
else 
    set(handles.uipanel5,'Visible', 'on')
end". In that code, there is not output, but i need the valeu of radio button. Is it 0 or 1 to be called (used) in function pushbutton2_Callback(hObject, eventdata, handles)..Do u know, how to do it??